# Quick Chinese input

Tags: chinese

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Quick Classic of Chinese input method.

I cannot flip to next page of the choices of words.

Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: You can have a try the key "PgDown" or "=", maybe it will works.

Comment: Yes. I made it by "=" to turn to next page and "-" to previous page. Many thanks.